# Angular test when a function is called when activated route has params

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write a test for a component where a function is called when activatedroute has segment `edit` in it

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.activatedRoute.url.subscribe((urlSegments) => {
        const currentRoute = urlSegments[0].path;
        console.log(currentRoute);
        if (currentRoute === "edit") {
          this.isEdit = true;
          this.id = params.id;
          this.populateForm(this.id);
        }
      });
}
```

this is the `ngOnInit` function and below are my tests

```
beforeEach(() => {
    mockNbToastrService = jasmine.createSpyObj(["show"]);
    mockNbDialogService = jasmine.createSpyObj(["open"]);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]),
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
      ],
      declarations: [ServiceCatalogComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: NbToastrService, useValue: mockNbToastrService },
        { provide: NbDialogService, useValue: mockNbDialogService },
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {
            params: of({ id: 123 }),
            url: of([
              {
                path: "edit",
              },
            ]),
          },
        },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ServiceCatalogComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });


it("should be in edit mode", () => {
    expect(fixture.componentInstance.isEdit).toBeTruthy();
  })

  it("should have an id if in edit mode", () => {
    expect(fixture.componentInstance.id).toBe(123);
  })

  it("should call populateForm when in edit mode", () => {
    spyOn(fixture.componentInstance, "populateForm");
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(fixture.componentInstance.populateForm).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

the first two tests are passing where isEdit mode is true and id is also set to 123 but the last test

`expect(fixture.componentInstance.populateForm).toHaveBeenCalled();` is not passing, i tried to use `fakeAsync`, `whenStable` and `flush()` but still the test is failing im not sure why?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fixture.detectChanges()` does not trigger `ngOnInit`. You need to explicitly call it

```
  it("should call populateForm when in edit mode", () => {
    spyOn(fixture.componentInstance, "populateForm");
    fixture.componentInstance.ngOnInit();
    expect(fixture.componentInstance.populateForm).toHaveBeenCalledWith(123);
  });
```

Comment: if ngonit is not called then how come the other tests passed?

Comment: @WasifKhalil: it was called the 1st time when you initialized the component in `beforeEach` block.

Comment: @WasifKhalil : Did my suggested code worked as expected ?

Comment: still confusing if ngoninit was called before then it should pass, anyway it worked, thanks

Comment: @WasifKhalil: it did not pass because your `spyOn` was put later, by that time `ngOnInit` was already called. Hence after `spyOn` you need to call explicitly